# Symfony exception KNPMenu builder does not exist for menu builder

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, menu, builder, knpmenu

I try the KnpMenu tutorial to create a menu, and use it with bootstrap in Symfony.
It works perfectly in local mode, but when I try it on my server (both in dev mode) it don't works, I have this error :

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Class "robStorm\WelcomeBundle\Menu\Builder" does not exist for menu
>   builder "robStormWelcomeBundle:Builder".") in
>   "robStormWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig". 500 Internal Server
>   Error - Twig_Error_Runtime 1 linked Exception:
>   InvalidArgumentException »

However, I have exactly the same files in local or on the server...

Here is the content of my file :

In app/config/config.yml :

```
# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            %kernel.debug%
    strict_variables: %kernel.debug%
twig:
    form:
        resources:
            - "BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:Form:form_div_layout.html.twig"
knp_menu:
   twig:
       template: "BraincraftedBootstrapBundle:Menu:menu.html.twig"
```

In src/robStorm/WelcomeBundle/Controller/HomepageController :

```
public function indexAction()
{
    return $this->render('robStormWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index.html.twig');
}
```

In src/robStorm/WelcomeBundle/Menu/builder.php :

```
<?php
namespace robStorm\WelcomeBundle\Menu;

use Knp\Menu\FactoryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Matcher;
use Knp\Menu\Matcher\Voter\UriVoter;
use Knp\Menu\MenuFactory;
use Knp\Menu\Renderer\ListRenderer;

class Builder extends ContainerAware
{

    public function mainMenu(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $item = $menu->addChild('Accueil', array('route' => 'robStormWelcomeBundle_homepage'));      
        $menu->addChild('Combat', array('route' => 'robStormWelcomeBundle_homepage_combat'));
        $menu->addChild('Boutique', array('uri' => '#'));


        return $menu;
    }

    public function menuDroite(FactoryInterface $factory, array $options)
    {
        $menu = $factory->createItem('root');

        $menu->addChild('Aide', array('uri' => '#'));
        $menu->addChild('d1', array('attributes' => array('divider' => true)));
        $dropdown = $menu->addChild('Mon compte');
        $dropdown->addChild('Mon profil', array('uri' => '#'));
        $dropdown->addChild('Mes messages', array('uri' => '#'));
        $dropdown->addChild('d1', array('attributes' => array('divider' => true)));
        $dropdown->addChild('Se déconnecter', array('uri' => '#'));

        return $menu;
    }


}
```

In src/robStorm/WelcomeBundle/Ressources/config/routing.yml :

```
robStormWelcomeBundle_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "robStormWelcomeBundle:Homepage:index" }
```

In src/robStorm/WelcomeBundle/Ressources/views/layout.html.twig :

```
<div class="container">
    {{ knp_menu_render('robStormWelcomeBundle:Builder:mainMenu', {'nav_type': 'navbar', 'currentAsLink': true}) }}
    {{ knp_menu_render('robStormWelcomeBundle:Builder:menuDroite', {'nav_type': 'navbar', 'currentAsLink': true, 'pull': 'right'}) }}
</div>
```

Comment: Simply put "builder" in place of "Builder" works, but why ??: {{knp_menu_render('robStormWelcomeBundle:builder:mainMenu', {'nav_type': 'navbar', 'currentAsLink': true}) }}

Answer (score 1):

**The problem** is with the case of the file/class.

If you use `robStormWelcomeBundle:Builder:mainMenu`, the server will look for a `src/robStorm/WelcomeBundle/Menu/Builder.php` file (notice the capitialized file name). But that file does not exists, you named it `builder.php` (lowercase).

The solution you did now (changing `...:Builder:mainMenu` to `...:builder:mainMenu`) is not that nice. That means PHP will look for a `builder` class, instead of the actual `Builder` class. Because PHP is a very lazy language, it will accept the `Builder` class instead of `builder`, but it is not nice to do so.

**The actual solution** if very simple: Rename `builder.php` to `Builder.php`.

> **The reason** why this don't happen in your local environment, but not on the server, is because a computer is lazy too (a server isn't).